# How to fill in from dynamic last row in one column to the last row in adjacent column?

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying some time now with the following problem: First code (not listed here) drops data in sheet EDD in column B (B45 to be precise), then each cell in col A is populated with number 1 (from A45 to the bottom of column B) - as the code below shows.

Now the problem is that I will be adding another set of data in column B (to the bottom of what has already been added) but this time this new data will have number 2 in each cell of the column A (ps. I cannot overwrite number 1's that I have already entered) - the issue is that the data is dynamic. I do not know how to identify the last row in column A (populated it with value = 2 and autofill it to the bottom of this new data in column B).

```
Dim EDDx As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long
Set EDDx = Sheets("EDD")
lastrow = EDDx.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
With EDDx
.Range("B45:B" & lastrow).Value = 1
End With
End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
with workSheets("EDD")
    .range(.cells(.rows.count, "B").end(xlup), _
           .cells(.rows.count, "C").end(xlup).offset(0, -1)).filldown
end with
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

Dim LastrowC As Long
Dim LastrowB As Long

With wsTest

    LastrowB = .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    LastrowC = .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    .Range("B" & Lastrow + 1 & ":C" & LastrowC).Value = "2"

End With


End Sub
```